# Background on the appendix of Evans' PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In Evans' PDE book Appendix A, he defines $C^k(\overline{U}) = \{ u \in C^k(U) \, \Big\rvert \,  D^\alpha u \, \text{is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of} \, U, \text{for all} \, |\alpha| \leq k \}$. He then says that if $u \in C^k(\overline{U})$, then $D^\alpha u$ continuously extends to $\overline{U}$ for each multi-index $\alpha$, $|\alpha| \leq k$.

My question is why does the first statement imply the next? Answers with references to precise theorem statements would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if $U$ is bounded and $f:U\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then $\lim_{x\to y}f(x)$ exist for all $y\in \partial U$. The way to prove is the following :

If $(a_n)\subset U$ is s.t. $a_n\to y\in \partial U$, then $(f(a_n))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. From this, you can get $\lim_{x\to y}f(x)$ exist.

Comment: Why don't we get a Cauchy sequence if $f$ is just continuous? Like we take a point $y \in \partial U$, by the definition of a boundary, there must be a sequence of points $\lim y_i = y$. Could we define $f(y) = \lim f(y_i)$?

Comment: For a counter example, take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $]0,1[$. @PhysicsEnthusiast

Comment: What does ] [ mean? Is it the same as (0, 1)?

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast: yes.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks! I'm still having trouble seeing how to prove that uniform continuity gives us what we want.

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast: Try first to prove that if $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ is uniforly continuous, then $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exist.